# In ActionScript 3.0, how can you control the order of initialization of members without using a constructor or init function?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, initialization

In ActionScript 3.0, this generates a runtime error:

```
private const MAX:int = 1;

private var m_iCount:int = MAX;

private var m_vVideos:Vector.<Video> = function():Vector.<Video> {
    var v:Vector.<Video> = new Vector.<Video>(MAX, true);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        v[i] = new Video();
    }
    return v;
}();
```

This doesn't:

```
private static const MAX:int = 1;

private var m_iCount:int = MAX;

private var m_vVideos:Vector.<Video> = function():Vector.<Video> {
    var v:Vector.<Video> = new Vector.<Video>(MAX, true);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        v[i] = new Video();
    }
    return v;
}();
```

The difference?  In the second one, `MAX` is static.  It will also work fine if `MAX` is non-static, but if you just pass a hard-coded `1` to the constructor for `Vector.<Video>`.  In the example where it throws an error, the problem is just that `MAX` hasn't been initialized yet.

Is there any way in AS3 to make a non-static `MAX` get defined and initialized before that function is called?  Can you control the order of initialization of members like that?

This is without using a constructor or init function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson provides a very handy article about your 'problem' and the order of initialization: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1038

Statics are basically initialized before normal variables.

Also I've found that most basic classes (ones that just extend Object) that have only constant declarations in them, are instantiated first. So you can even do things like:

```
public function test(param:String = BasicClass.PUBLIC_CONSTANT):void { }
```

Comment: Assuming `MAX` and `m_vVideos` are both non-static, is there a way to make it initialize `MAX` before `m_vVideos`, when `m_vVideos` is initialized to a function's return value?  Is that function being treated as a part of the class constructor?

Comment: You cannot 'sort' the initialization order, and it's best to do these things WHEN the class instantiates. For example call a simple `initialize` function from the very first line of your constructor and make all the initializations there. If you want to use it as static - call static **method** instead of public var instead, and do the initialization there. What you want cannot be accomplished that way.